# Angularjs how to achieve export xls file without using window.location.href

Tags: angularjs

```
I have a service which returns xls and I want to get & save that xls file dialog 
 when I use 
  ex: window.location.href in jquery its coming but i am forcing to use angularjs

but I dont want to use this **window.location.href** instead of this
```

I am writing  angularjs code below for achieve without using  window.location.href

ex:
      The XLS file type is primarily associated with 'Excel' by Microsoft Corporation. Program: EXCEL.EXE. Also used by the Excel Viewer: XLVIEW.EXE. Can be captured by the OpenOffice Suite. Note: This file type can become infected and should be carefully scanned if someone sends you a file with this extension. Excel files can also be read and saved by the OpenOffice Suite.

so same like that above description i need to get any example in angularjs
    here ajaxFactory is my own factory method like this

```
ajaxCommon.factory('ajaxFactory', function ($http) {
 var ajaxFactory = {
 ajaxRequest: function (url, params, method) {
   }
};
return ajaxFactory;
});

 so i am using that method for get the data like below in one angularjs controller
 by invoking that factory inside controller

 The below example used Ajax call for achieve the above window.location.href 
  but i am not  getting can anyone tell solution for this.
ex:
app.controller("Test",["ajaxFactory",function("ajaxFactory"){
   ajaxFactory.ajaxRequest("/app/dao/v5/sample?a=getData",{
      'exportType':'EXPORT_XLS'},"POST").then(function(data){
          var element = angular.element('<a/>');element.attr({
          href: 'data:attachment/vnd.ms-excel,' + data,
          target: '_blank',
          download: 'sample_reports.xls'
          })[0].click();});
     }
     ]);
```

Comment: why don't you just do window.open ??

Comment: please can u any example for this using angularjs but not jquery at all

Comment: this is not angular or jquery thing, this is just javascript. just do window.open('http://www.example.com/path/to/file/file.ext'))
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: ok,is there any possibility to do in angularjs for export xls functionality. If there means please can u give one example either fiddle or plunker.

Comment: what do you mean by export xls??

Comment: please see this example http://www.directiv.es/ng-csv  Here how to write xls format without display popup. suppose this example u clicked export button then u will get download file,when ever we clicked it is displaying popup then click on ok button its coming csv format,so same like that without displaying that popup i need to display xls format directly when i click on download file. are u understand dude..

Comment: xls is a very complex format, but most excel readers interpret csv,tsv and xml perfectly, so you should consider converting to one of those formats instead

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

a) You can save Excel file with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) + [XLSX.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) libraries:

Alasql can generate XLSX file from JavaScript array and save it to file, like below:

```
function myCtrl(scope) {
    $scope.data = [{a:1},{a:2}];
    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("mydata.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[$scope.data]
}
```

See [the Angular.js example](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/00nfeq12/) at jsFiddle.

b) Do it "by hand" if you generate Excel file yourself. Include [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library 
into you project, then call saveAs() function, like below.

```
    // Create wb spreadsheet object for XLSX.js
    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb,wopts);  // Generate binary file with xlsx data

    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:""}), filename); // Save binary file to file with dialog

    function s2ab(s) {        // Special utility to conert data to ArrayBuffer
      var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
      var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
      for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
      return buf;
    }
```